# How to compile old version kernel and install it?

Tags: unix, kernel

I am using fedora 21,and kernel version is 3.17 but I compile a 2.6.32 kernel and install it,when I reboot I got error :"too old kernel",how Can I install a rather older kernel on a new system,is there some way fix it?

Comment: Why do you need that? I'm not saying you can't hack it somehow to make it work, but  2.6.32 is quite old for fast moving fedora (this kernel version is now shipped in rhel 6).

Comment: My company servers are working an rhel 5 or rhel 6,I want to build such a kernel on my computer.

Comment: In this case, it would be better just to use rhel (or centos) 6 machine for this. Virtual machine would be enough (you may like to check virt-builder[1] to quickly create one).

[1] https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2013/10/05/new-tool-virt-builder/

Comment: please use the `flag` at the bottom of your question and ask the moderator to move to http://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.